# Issue using sprintf to insert variable into SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I'm running an R script that grabs a query from MySQL. The query itself is functional, but is dependent on a variable "N".

To add this variable to my SQL code, I'm using sprintf to insert it by typing `%s` where I'd like it. However, my query also includes multiple of these `LIKE` statements:

```
FROM `Receipts`

WHERE `RetailerID`

IN ( '%s' ) # this is where "N" is placed

AND ( `Date` LIKE  '%01/07/2014%')
```

I'm positive that this is the reason my query is not running. The `sprintf` command is having issue when it reaches these `LIKE` commands, probably thinking it is similar to `%s`.

Does anyone know how to get around this so that `%01/07/2014%` is still printed to the SQL query? I've tried using the escape `%%` like this, `%%01/07/2014%%` but it still doesn't work.

Is there a way I can format `sprintf` so it knows to skip these?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use two `%s` where the second is for the date, then insert the date as well

Comment: please dont tag spam

Comment: You shouldn't use sprintf to build sql queries.

Comment: I usually use `gsub` for such things. Then you can use specific place holders (like `@N`) for your variables and replace these selectively.

Comment: if I shouldn't sprintf, what's an easier method?

Comment: If I use gsub, should I set it up like sql <- "QUERY" then gsub("@N","N",sql) where @N is the placement and N is the variable? @cryo111

Comment: when you had php tagged I could have told you, but in r, don't know

Comment: Try something like this: `N=10;query="select * from table where table.cnt=@N";gsub("@N",N,query);`

Answer (score 2):

To make @cryo111's comment an explicit answer:

Use `gsub` like this:

```
N=10
query="select * from table where table.cnt=@N"
gsub("@N",N,query)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RMySQL's](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/index.html) dbEscapeString with sprintf to handle placeholders.

```R
require(RMySQL)

con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = "foobar")
tmp <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM someField WHERE someOtherField = %s", "sometext")
dbEscapeStrings(con, tmp)
```

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf` works fine for me provided I escape the `%` signs:

```
x <- "from receipts where retailerid in ('%s') and (date like '%%01/07/2014%%')"
> sprintf(x,"a")
[1] "from receipts where retailerid in ('a') and (date like '%01/07/2014%')"
```

The above runs just fine for me. However, in general, I wouldn't recommend `sprintf` over `gsub` just because it will become cumbersome fairly quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use paste for sql queries. So in your case I would use something like:

```
paste("select * from Receipts where RetailerID in(",as.character(N),") and (date like '%01/07/2014%')"
```